# PHP - Compare two MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a PHP code that let's you compare 2 MySQL tables with each other and lets you add missing entries into one?

I have two tables. hs_hr_employee and rights. I want to add data from certain columns from the hs_hr_employee table so that they would be the same in the rights tables.

hs_hr_employee has multiple rows, whereas the rights table has 5 rows. The rights table gets the info from 4 columns from the hs_hr_employee table, emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname

Below is the code:

```
    <?php

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','admin','root');

if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    if( isset( $_POST['cb_change'] ) && is_array( $_POST['cb_change'] ))
    {
        foreach( $_POST['cb_change']  as $emp_number => $permission)
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE `rights` SET Permission='".mysql_real_escape_string($permission)."' WHERE emp_number='".mysql_real_escape_string($emp_number)."'";
            echo __LINE__.": sql: {$sql}\n";
            mysql_query( $sql );
        }
    }
}
?>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    <span style="font-size:36px;"><strong><span style="font-family: trebuchet ms,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="color: rgb(0, 128, 128);">File Database - Administration Panel</span></span></strong></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    &nbsp;</p>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
table, td, th
{
border:1px solid #666;
font-style:Calibri;
}
th
{
background-color:#666;
color:white;
font-style:Calibri;
}
</style>
</head>

    <form method="post" action="admin.php">

    <?php 


        if (!$connection)
          {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }

        mysql_select_db('users', $connection);

        //mysql_query('INSERT into rights(Emp_num, ID, Name, Surname) SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname FROM hs_hr_employee');


        $result = mysql_query("SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname, Permissions FROM rights");

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO rights (emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname)
                    SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname
                    FROM hs_hr_employee
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE employee_id = VALUES(employee_id), emp_number = VALUES(emp_number)
                    ");

        echo "<center>";

        echo "<table >
        <tr>
        <th>Employee Number</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Permissions</th>
        <th>Change</th>
        </tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['emp_number'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['employee_id'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['emp_firstname'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['emp_lastname'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['Permissions'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td> <select name='cb_change[]'><option value='all'>All</option> <option value='remote'>Remote Gaming</option> <option value='landbased'>Landbased Gaming</option> <option value='general'>General Gaming</option> </select> </td>"; 
          echo "</tr>" ;
          }


          #echo "<td>" . $row['Change'] . "</td>";


          echo "</table>";

          echo "</center>";


        #$_POST['cb_permissions'];


     mysql_close($connection);


    ?>

<p style="text-align: center;">
    &nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    &nbsp;</p>

<p style="text-align: right;">
    <input name="Save_Btn" type="button" value="Save" />


    </p>


</form>
```

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `php`

Comment: it is mysql through php on intel CPU - so add `intel` tag then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with an `INSERT INTO SELECT` here.

Assume you recognize an employee by the Social Security Number (ssn), and you use this value to update, for instance, name and birthyear:

```
mysql_query("
INSERT INTO hs_hr_employee (ssn, name, birthyear)
SELECT ssn, name, birthyear
FROM hs_hr_rights
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name), birthyear = VALUES(birthyear)
");
```

You can also add a `WHERE` in between `FROM` and `ON DUPLICATE`. Like so:

```
...
FROM hs_hr_rights
WHERE birthyear IS NULL
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name), birthyear = VALUES(birthyear)
...
```

Although, I don't see the need of copying values since in most cases you can fetch them through `JOIN`s.

Comment: What I tried is this, but it seems it's not working: `mysql_query('SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname FROM hs_hr_employee
     WHERE hs_hr_employee.ID
     NOT IN (
     SELECT rights.ID
     FROM rights
     WHERE hs_hr_employee.ID=rights.ID
     )');`

Comment: I tried yours now, but it's not updating the values, the rights table is still empty

Comment: Are you sure you're replacing the correct columns and table names?

Comment: I named them the same in both tables for the same reason. I'll put the full code in the main question.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table a where a.common not in (select b.common from table b where a.common = b.common)
```

And run this as well

```
select * from table b where b.common not in (select a.common from table a where a.common = b.common)
```

Not possible in php but in mysql its ans is as above

Comment: mysql_query() is used to fiere ny sql query from php