# How to compare 2 table with multiple column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to compare multiple column such as part, quantity, and type with another table. I tried with compare part id without problem but when I want to compare part id with quantity it will cause error such as return nothing.

Below coding is for compare part id only.

```
INSERT INTO `table3` 
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   table2
                   WHERE  table2.part = table1.part)
```

How can I compare part and quantity together to find unmatched record.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please put some efforts in framing a question with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Compare two MySQL tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565288/php-compare-two-mysql-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A handy method in MySQL is `in` with tuples:

```
INSERT INTO `table3` ( . . . )
    SELECT . . .
    FROM table1
    WHERE (part, quantity) NOT IN (SELECT part, quantity FROM table2);
```

More importantly, you should explicitly list all the columns when using an `insert`.  This helps prevent unexpected problems when inserting data.

Comment: if the part id is match and quantity not match, and it will return unmatched records rows right?thanks

Comment: @catcat123 . . . Both values need to match to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions -

1)

```
 INSERT INTO `table3` 
    SELECT *
    FROM   table1
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                       FROM   table2
                       WHERE  table2.part = table1.part And table2.quantity=table1.quantity)
```

2)

```
INSERT INTO table2 (part, quantity, type)
SELECT part, quantity, type
FROM table1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity= VALUES(quantity), type= VALUES(type)
```

Comment: if using solutions 1,when part id is match and quantity not match will also return the unmatched record right?

Comment: @catcat123 no it will not retuurn

Comment: if i want return the unmatched record when part id is match and quantity not match, how to do that?thanks

Comment: Just change the condition in first query from table2.quantity=table1.quantity to table2.quantity<>table1.quantity

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best approach, but I'd be tempted to try a null-left-join on either a set of values or a concatenation - e.g.

```
select t1.*
from mytable1 as t1
left join mytable2 as t2 on t1.foo = t2.foo and t1.bar = t2.bar
where t1.id is null;
```

The only thing to note is that t1.id (and t2.id) are assumed to be the primary key - i.e. can never be null. The end result of the above should be all the rows in t1 that cannot be joined to a row in t2.